Kendo MVC Editor not saving hyperlink styling when saved to database
When I add a hyperlink to my Kendo Editor, it appears to underline the link and add some default styling to indicate a link as below:

However, when this is saved to the database, it appears as a regular text link (example: a href="www.cnn.com") and does not contain any underlining styling to look like a link (example: a href="www.cnn.com" style="text-decoration:underline").
How can I specify that when saved to the database the underline styling is added without having to manipulate the string?
